# Guts of 3-manifolds for sutured manifolds and pared manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, 3-manifolds

I found the notion "guts of three-manifolds" unclear to me. There exists "**sutured guts**" and "**pared guts**" in the literature, the well definedness of both are vague to me.

**Sutured guts**: The following definition of sutured guts is cited from the preprint [Guts in Sutured Decompositions and the Thurston Norm](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.12095) by Agol and Zhang. Let $(M,\gamma)$ be a taut sutured 3-manifold, where $\gamma$ is a collection of disjoint annuli and tori on the boundary $\partial M$. Let $R(\gamma)=\partial M\setminus int(\gamma)=R_+\cup R_-$, where $R_+$ and $R_-$ are oriented according to the orientation of $\gamma$. We further define

- A *product disk* is a disk $D$ in $M$ such that $D\cap \gamma$ consists of two arcs.
- A *product annulus* is an essential annulus $A$ in $M$ such that one component of $A$ lies on $R_-$ and another component of $R_+$ lies on $R_-$.

Decompose $(M,\gamma)$ along a maximal collection of disjoint nonparallel product annuli and product disks, throw away all product components (called the window) of the resulting sutured manifold, the remaining sutured manifold $(\overline M,\overline \gamma)$ is called the sutured guts of $(M,\gamma)$. **It is well defined up to isotopy by JSJ-decomposition**.

**Pared guts**: In this artical [The minimal volume orientable hyperbolic 2-cusped 3-manifold](https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.0043) by Agol, the guts of a pared manifold $(M,P)$ is defined as follows. A *pared manifold* $(M,P)$ is a pair where $M$ is a compact orientable irreducible 3-manifold and $P$ is a union of essential annuli and tori on the boundary $\partial M$, such that every abelian noncyclic subgroup of $\pi_1(M)$ is peripheral with respect to $P$, and every mapping of an annulus $(A,\partial A)\rightarrow (M,P)$ that is injective on the fundamental group can be homotoped into $P$.

Let $(M,P)$ be a pared manifold such that $\partial_0M:=\partial M\setminus P$ is incompressible. **There is a canonical family of annuli** (I suspect that one should also consider tori here?) $(A,\partial A)\subset (M,\partial_0M)$ which is the maximal collection of nonparallel essential annuli such that every other essential annulus $(B,\partial B)\subset (M,\partial_0M)$ can be relatively isotoped to be disjoint with $A$. A components of $M\setminus A$ is called a *window* if it is an ($I$-bundle, $\partial I$-bundle). Let $W$ be the union of such components. Then $M\setminus W$ is called the pared guts of $(M,P)$, which is also a pared manifold, with pared locus $\partial(M\setminus W)-\partial_0M$.

**My question is:**

- How to apply the JSJ-decomposition to see the well definedness of the sutured guts? I thought about the Characteristic Pair Theorem to produce a canonical seifert pair $(\Sigma,\Phi)\subset (M,R(\gamma))$, the frontier of the $I$-bundle components of $(\Sigma, \Phi)\subset (M,R(\gamma))$ seems to be the desired maximal collection of product annuli and product disks, but I am not sure. I also found that in the paper [The virtual fibering theorem for 3-manifolds](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.4799) by Friedl and Kitayama, before Lemma 3.2 they said the guts may depend on the choice of the disks and annuli, which confuses me.
- Why is the pared guts well defined? In other words, why is there a canonical set of annuli as in the definition? Is it from the Characteristic Pair Theorem?
- What is the relation between pared guts and the sutured guts? Why do we need to consider product disks in the sutured case, but not in the pared case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edited:** to reflect the correct definitions.

---

**Question 1:** Why are the guts well-defined?

**Answer 1:** By the JSJ theory there is a unique collection of $I$-bundles (and Seifert fibered spaces) that contain (up to isotopy) all essential product disks and product annuli (and all essential tori).  We throw away the $I$-bundles. Note that any Seifert fibered pieces remaining are pared solid tori.  (There are no interesting Seifert fibered pieces because the original manifold $M$ has "non-degenerate" Thurston norm.  So all essential tori in $M$ are parallel to boundary components.)

**Question 2:** Why is the pared guts well defined?

**Answer 2:** For exactly the same reason.

**Question 3:** What is the relation between pared guts and the sutured guts?

**Answer 3:** Pared guts are directed at understanding geometry.  Sutured guts have an additional homological condition (the assumption of tautness).

**Question 4:** Why do we need to consider product disks in the sutured case, but not in the pared case?

**Answer 4:** We don't need them in either case.  Consider the frontier  of a regular neighbourhood of the union of a product disk and the sutures it meets.

Comment: I have more questions to Answer 1: the characteristic pair theorem gives Seifert submanifolds and I-bundles. The Seifert submanifolds contain annuli as well. should I further decompose the Seifert submanifolds along annuli to produce I-bundles and solid tori with sutures? Is there any reference for this argument?

Comment: We do not decompose the Seifert fibered spaces. Instead we throw them away.

Comment: For a general reference on sutured manifold theory, I recommend Martin Scharlemann’s articles “Lectures on the theory of sutured 3-manifolds” and (the much longer) “Sutured manifolds and generalised Thurston norms”.

Comment: Why not decompose the Seifert manifolds? They may contain essential annuli as well, I thought we had to cut along those annuli to result in an I-bundle (which we throw away) and some solid torus with sutures on the boundary (which we keep as guts), for example, let M be a Seifert manifold with two sutures on the boundary, such that the two sutures are parallel to the fiber of M, it contains non-trivial guts, right?

Comment: I've edited my answer to more directly address the (lack of) Seifert fibered pieces.  Previously I was not using the hypotheses correctly.

Comment: Your answer certainly resolves my problem! But in Agol and Zhang's paper, the well-definedness of guts is general, and does not need the manifold to have non-degenerate Thurston norm. According to JSJ-theory, I-bundles and $S^1$-pairs $(S,T)$ contain all essential annuli and tori, where $S$ is a Seifert manifold and $T\subset \partial S$ is union of fibers. To define guts, we should continue cutting essential annuli $(A,\partial A)\subset (S,T)$, finally we get an I-bundle and some solid tori (containing singular fibers as core) with suture on the boundary. That's the picture in my head now.

Comment: Excellent - I think we are on the same page.  If my answer has answered your question you should consider accepting it (by clicking the "check mark").

Comment: Of course! Thanks a lot!